How do I build bundled AMD libraries with interdependencies with webpack (using openlayers and vue3-layers)
I am trying to use webpack so I can build my dependencies from node_modules instead of cdns. I need them built as AMD modules. This has all been fairly straight forward so far with a fairly basic config and the libraryTarget: "amd".
This has all worked relatively smoothly, however I have recently tried to build vue3-openlayers which has a dependencies on various openlayers packages. When I try to build this bundle it results in an enormous bundle size as the entire ol AND ol-ext package is bundled into my build - making it so big its unusable.
This results in an enormous bundle size despite ol deps being listed in the externals object ...
const vueLayers = {
  entry: {
    "vue3-openlayers": "vue3-openlayers",
  },
  name: "vuelayers",
  externals: {
    vue: "amd vue-3",
    ol: "amd ol",
    "ol-contextmenu": "amd ol-contextmenu",
    "ol-ext": "amd ol-ext",
    geotiff: "amd geotiff"
  },
  output: {
    ...libsOutputConfig,
    filename: getFileName,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./libs/bundles"),
    library: {
      name: "vue3-openlayers",
      type: "amd",
      export: "default"
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        ],
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset/inline"
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              url: false
            }
          },
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              url: false
            }
          },
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: devTool,
};

Results in ...
vuelayers:
  asset vue3-openlayers/vue3-openlayers.dev.js 6.37 MiB [compared for emit] (name: vue3-openlayers) 1 related asset
  orphan modules 250 KiB [orphan] 21 modules
  runtime modules 937 bytes 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/ol/ 3.49 MiB 321 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/ol-ext/ 918 KiB 46 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/color-space/*.js 7.92 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/ol-contextmenu/dist/*.css 11.5 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/*.js 6.74 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 2.74 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/color-parse/ 8.29 KiB
    ./node_modules/color-parse/index.js 4.09 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/color-parse/node_modules/color-name/index.js 4.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
  + 9 modules



I have ol already built out as amd bundle so vue3-openlayers should use this and this would significantly reduce the size of the bundle
I tried using the babel amd plug-in - this did correctly mark ol as an external rather than adding it to the bundle (progress) but here I run into another issue...
The module then anticipates each ES6 module of ol to be defined at an AMD modules.
define(["exports","ol/Feature.js","ol/Geolocation.js","ol/Map.js"....

When instead what I need is something like
define(["exports", "ol", "ol-ext", "ol-contextmenu", "vue"], function(exports2, ol, olExt, olContextMenu, vue) {
  var Feature = ol.Feature;
  var Geolocation = ol.Geolocation;
  var Map$1 = ol.Map;
  var Overlay = ol.Overlay;
  var proj4$1 = ol.proj.proj4;
  var Projection$1 = ol.proj.Projection;
  var View = ol.View;
  var proj = ol.proj;
  var source = ol.source;
  var animations= ol.easing;
  var HeatmapLayer = ol.layer.Heatmap;
  var ImageLayer = ol.layer.Image;
  var LayerGroup = ol.layer.Group;

Is this impossible to do?
PS This is my first ever stack overlfow question please be kind :)
